# importing namespace the correct way

Tags: typescript

How do I use class from a namespace, that is either same, or different with current file namespace?

Currently I have the below 2 file.
TypeA.ts:

```
export namespace Game {
@ccclass
export class TypeA extends cc.Component {

    protected onLoad(): void {
        // do something
    }
}}
```

TypeB.ts:

```
import * s from "some url";

export namespace Game {
@ccclass
export class TypeB extends s.Game.TypeA {

    protected onLoad(): void {
        // do something
    }
}}
```

As you can see the import part, vscode said 'as' is expected, but currently I can key in any strings and it somehow work.
And the TypeB extends part looks ugly and long.

How can I make it just TypeB extends TypeA since both have the same namespace?
There's actually still tons of diff class/components that I plan on to put under the same namespace, should I do that tough? or just remove the export namespace part and let every export class more easily accesible?

Comment: Why do you need both exports and namespaces, for the first part? These are two different ways to structure code, I'd suggest to choose one or another.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other kind of declaration, two namespaces with the same name are only "the same namespace" if they are defined in the same scope: either global or the same parent namespace or external module.  In your example, you have two different namespaces named `Game`, one in each module.  If you wanted to add to the same namespace from both modules, you could use the following in TypeA.ts:

```
declare global {
    namespace Game {
        class TypeA extends cc.Component {
            onLoad(): void;
        }
    }
}
Game.TypeA = <any>function(this: Game.TypeA) {
    // constructor
};
Game.TypeA.prototype.onLoad = function() {
    // do something
};
```

and similarly in TypeB.ts.  As you can see, this gets extremely ugly because the `declare global` can contain only declarations and the implementation has to be patched in separately.  You're probably better off following Cerberus's suggestion to pick either namespaces or external modules.